# NSMutableArray Extra Nil Sentinels

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I've read a text file into an array of strings. In the below code I'm creating objects from that array and adding them into an NSMutableArray.

```
NSMutableArray* metaphors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
unsigned int i, cnt = [allLinedStrings count];
for(i = 0; i < cnt-3; i+=5)
{
    Metaphor *newMetaphor = [[Metaphor alloc] init];
    [newMetaphor setMetaphorTitle: allLinedStrings[i]];
    [newMetaphor setCorrectAnswer: allLinedStrings[i+1]];
    [newMetaphor setLiteralAnswer: allLinedStrings[i+2]];
    [newMetaphor setWayOffAnswer: allLinedStrings[i+3]];
    [metaphors addObject:newMetaphor];
}
```

As for the problem, when I access any item via index ([metaphors objectAtIndex:3] for example) every other element (odd numbered ones) are nil elements. All of the objects are added to the array, though. My guess is that addObject is adding an element to the array as well as a new nil sentinel every time? Should this be happening/should I manually go through and remove these elements?

Also a side note, as I'm new to Objective-C, my Metaphor class contains the 4 instance fields you can see within the body: I'm sure there is quicker syntax to initialize one of these objects if anyone could point me the right way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSArray can't contain nil. It's invalid. If you are getting nil back in a call to an array, the array pointer itself is almost certainly nil. (You CAN send messages to a nil object pointer in Objective C. It simply returns nil/zero.)

Trying to add a nil to an NSArray will cause a crash, and trying to index past the end of an NSArray will also crash.

There is a special class NSNull that provides a singleton placeholder object that can take the place of a nil entry in an NSArray.

Comment: Yeah, my problem turned out to be related to reading the file, not adding the objects to the array. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The nil sentinel is only a way to know the last element of a variable length array has been reached. The nil sentinel ISN'T added to the NSMutableArray;

NSMutableArray addObject method doesn't need a nil sentinel as you only add ONE object, not a variable length array.

If you need to add something "nil" to an array, you might use [NSNull null] which is an object "equivalent to nil".